# Call a field inside a class dynamically

Tags: apex, json, class, webservices

I have a JSON that I get as a webservice and deserialize it into classes.

The classes are :

```
 public class DataStructure{
      public String Name;
        public String Code;
        public String Description;
        public String Token;
        public Results Result;
 }




public class Results {
        public String Id;
        public String Date;
        public String Time;
        public List<Custom_ObjectA> A;
        public List<Custom_ObjectB> B;
        public List<Custom_ObjectC> C;

    }



public class Custom_ObjectA  {
        public String IU;
        public String name;
        public String mcv;
        public String nhg;
    }

public class Custom_ObjectB  {
        public String IU;
        public String name;
        public String mcv;
        public String nhg;
    }

public class Custom_ObjectC  {
        public String IU;
        public String name;
        public String mcv;
        public String nhg;
    }


 DataStructure response = (DataStructure)JSON.deserialize(JSON, DataStructure.class);
```

Inside the class DataStructure I have a Name variable - This Name is one of the types of the lists inside Result class.

That means that the name will be Custom_ObjectA , Custom_ObjectB Or Custom_ObjectC

I would like to check the size of the list that I got in the Results class.
(Those 3 are just an example.. I have like 24 different lists).

I want to do something like :

```
response.result.'response.Name'.size()
```

how can I achieve that? (I would like not to go over all of them in a loop)

Comment: Consider just making the `Result` have one massive list of `List<Object>`, which would actually be a list of all the custom classes you are parsing.  Then you could `JSON.deserializeUntyped()` each of them and get their values based on the `Map<String, Object>` format

Comment: I agree that Maps seem a better approach here. You could have a Map based on type for your A, B and C lists in Results; "Map<Type, List<Object>> ABCs", accessing these via ABCs."List<Object> theAs = result.ABCs.get(Custom_ObjectA.class);" - the only downside; you will need to cast when you access the entries from this list.

Comment: BTW, as you probably found out already, Apex does not support method-level reflection (and barely supports any sort of reflection at all - just the ability to instantiate an object of a given class, using the Type functionality or in JSON deserialization) AFAIK.

Comment: @PhilW Combined with an Apex property accessor, Map<Type...> or Map<String...>  would work, cast and String/Type conversion could be all encapsulated.